# Почему не работает перегрузка класса с шаблоном?

Tags: c++

С одним шаблоном все работает, но когда добавляешь шаблон внутри другого, перегрузка не работает.

Не понимаю что не так.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Testclass
{
public:
    Testclass(T1& a, T1& b, T2& f)
    {
        cout << a << "\n" << endl;
        cout << b << "\n" << endl;
        cout << f << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Myclass : public Testclass<T1, T2>
{
public:
    Myclass(T1& a, T1& b, T2& f)
    {
        Testclass<T1, T2>(a, b, f);
    }
};

int main()
{    
    int a = 2,
        b = 5;
    string f = "test";

    Myclass<int, string>(a, b, f);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97572/discussion-on-question-by-loli-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строчка: `Testclass<T1, T2>(a, b, f);` делает не то, что вы думаете. Она создает *временный* объект, который тут же удаляется.

Вызов конструктора нужно поставить в список инициализации:

```
Myclass(T1& a, T1& b, T2& f) : Testclass<T1, T2>(a, b, f) {}
```

Comment: Но мне не нужно вызывать через инициализацию, иначе я не смогу делать много вызовов.

Comment: @loli То есть `Testclass<T1, T2>(a, b, f);` делает ровно то, что вы хотели? Вам нужен временный объект?

Comment: Мне нужна возможность вызывать много Testclass, внутри Myclass
Причем вызовы могут быть в разном порядке.

Comment: Ну это не совсем класс эта функция с таким же именем как класс.

Comment: @loli Вы хотите вызвать несколько конструкторов `Testclass` для одного и того же объекта? Так нельзя делать. Перенесите нужные действия в методы `Testclass`.

Comment: Нет я хочу сделать перегрузку то что вы описали я и так могу сделать :)

Comment: @loli Что-то я вообще не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Можете подробнее рассказать, что хотите получить? Вообще, что именно вы хотите перегрузить?

Comment: Можно вызвать шаблон внутри класса вот таким способом

Myclass<T1, T2>::newTestclass(a, b, f);
Но для этого в классе Testclass вам понадобится создать уникальную функцию.
Я же пытаюсь сделать перегрузку и избавится от уникальной функции оставив только класс.

Comment: @loli Опять, ничего непонятно. Объясните нормально. `Myclass<T1, T2>::newTestclass(a, b, f);` *"вызвать шаблон"* Где здесь вызов шаблона? `newTestclass` - это шаблон? *"внутри класса"* Какого класса? `Testclass`? *"для этого в классе Testclass вам понадобится создать уникальную функцию"* Зачем? *"сделать перегрузку"* Перегрузку чего? Функции? Констркутора?